# Jmeter, Regular expression with extra space on either side

Tags: regex, jmeter

Following is the expression from which I want to extract "Skytours"
                     Skytours

I used the (\s*.+?), but still not able to extract the value. Can you kindly suggest how i can handle extra space on either side of the required word

Answer (score 0):

```
(\w+)\s*(?=<\/span>)
```

Try this.Grab the capture or group.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iY3eK8/1

Comment: still not able to capture. As the expression contains html tags i am not able to post the exact expression.Skytours has lot of extra space before S and after s

Comment: No, As i have to generalize the regular expression, it should be unique. With the above mentioned regs i cant capture the specific value

Comment: @SylviaLobo Can you paste your content there and share the link

Comment: i am bale to proceed with CSS/Jquery. Thank you for the help